# Interval look-up on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

There are two dataframes, `df_A` and `df_B`

```
df_A
Out[61]: 
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2  60
2  3  40

df_B
Out[62]: 
   A   B   D
0  1   5  10
1  1  10  25
2  1  20  60
3  2   5  10
4  2  10  25
5  2  20  60
6  3  10  20
7  3  15  40
8  3  25  80
```

Now I need to left join `df_A` and `df_B` on column `A` and `B`, the tricky part is `df_B` is to be considered as follows

```
df_B
Out[64]: 
   A        B   D
0  1   [5,10)  10
1  1  [10,20)  25
2  1    [20:)  60
3  2   [5,10)  10
4  2  [10,20)  25
5  2    [20:)  60
6  3  [10,15)  20
7  3  [15,25)  40
8  3    [25:)  80
```

So for values of `B` greater than equal to 5 and less than 10, value '10' should be returned when `df_A['A'] == 1`

My output dataframe should be like this

```
df_C
Out[66]: 
   A   B   D
0  1  10  25
1  2  60  60
2  3  40  80
```

Comment: That are pandas dataframes?

Comment: I don't understand why the `60` in `df_A.B` becomes a 30 in your desired output.  I don't see 30 listed anywhere.

Comment: `[5,10)` would exclude a value of 10.  Is that intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more pandas / vectorized way to do this but here is an option:

```
C = []
for A, B in zip(df_A['A'],df_A['B']):
    idx = ((df_B[df_B['A']==A]['B'] > B).cumsum() == 0).sum() - 1
    C.append(df_B[df_B['A']==A].iloc[idx,-1])

df_C = df_A.copy(deep=True).assign(C=C)
```

now

```
>>> df_C
   A   B   C
0  1  10  25
1  2  60  60
2  3  40  80
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question now.. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Venky you still have a renegade `30` in your `df_C`. I suspect it is actually a typo in your `df_A`...

Comment: I need to run this code on larger dataframe, As you mentioned there will be more vectorized way of doing this, Can you suggestion where to look or which function to be used to solve this

Comment: Not really. Try this first, and make sure it really is too slow though before you go off trying to optimize it.